# Using AVCaptureAudioDataOutput to record data instead of AVAudioRecorder

Tags: swift, xcode, avaudiorecorder

Currently I am using the code mentioned below to record audio using AVAudioRecorder. However I would like frame level recording of audio for mz project, so I need to use AVCaptureAudioDataOutput and it's setSampleBufferDelegate method. is there any was I can modify the code below minimallly so that I can have frame/level audio information? maybe transferring the data from AVAudioRecorder to AVCaptureAudioDataOutput... not sure...

```
     audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.record()
```